# Mysql trigger is not working

Tags: mysql, triggers

I've created following trigger but it not executing after inserting data

```
DELIMITER //
  CREATE TRIGGER sale_after_insert
AFTER INSERT
   ON ano_sale_join
FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ano_sale_join.database_inventory (sale_id) values (NEW.sale_id);
    INSERT INTO ano_sale_join.database_inventory (sales_prod_id) values (NEW.sales_prod_id);
  END//
DELIMITER;
```

Comment: `ano_sale_join` is a database or a table?

Comment: @GajananGadam: then what is `database_inventory`?

Comment: @Ravinder its a database

Comment: Unless `ano_sale_join` is a database and `database_inventory` is a table, it fails to compile.

Comment: why are you `inserting` twice on a *single* table from same *NEW* row values?

Comment: Also give relation between tables `ano_sale_join` and `ano_sale_join`. And are they part of the same database?

Comment: @Ravinder after on i've given table is 'ano_sale_join'

Comment: @Ravinder and after that in insert query i've mention the database name i.e database_inventory

Comment: @Ravinder will u correct this trigger

Comment: @GajananGadam: Check my answer. Comment on it for more queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a wrong reference of `database` and `table` in the statements. They got *swapped*.

This code block is wrong:

```
INSERT INTO ano_sale_join.database_inventory (sale_id) values (NEW.sale_id);
INSERT INTO ano_sale_join.database_inventory (sales_prod_id) values (NEW.sales_prod_id);
```

Change them as:

```
INSERT INTO database_inventory.ano_sale_join(sale_id) values (NEW.sale_id);
INSERT INTO database_inventory.ano_sale_join(sales_prod_id) values (NEW.sales_prod_id);
```

**Refer to**:

- [Create Trigger Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-trigger.html)

Comment: still this trigger not inserting data into ano_sale_join table

Comment: Don't we all love accepted answers with a "does not work" note from the OP? ;-P

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: It seems that, comment was made exactly 1 min before the answer was accepted. But I too am not sure if the issue is resolved. OP has to declare it.